# deleting rows and sections from UITableView swift

Tags: swift, tableview, rows

I am trying to swipe to delete cells from my tableview and every time I attempt to do so I get an error.

This is my code for the actual deletion

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.feedData.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row) // also remove an array object if exists.
        self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(NSArray(object: NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row, inSection: 1)) as [AnyObject], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Left)
       // self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(NSArray(object: NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row, inSection: 1)) as [AnyObject], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Left)
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }    
}
```

And this is what I am returning in my sections

```
 override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}
```

I am a beginner so bear with me :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the following two functions to handle swipe deletion:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Bool {
   return true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
   if (editingStyle == .Delete) {
    // handle delete (by removing the data from your array and updating the tableview)

    self.tableView.beginUpdates()

    self.feedData.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row) // also remove an array object if exists.
    self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Left)

    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

The function `tableView(_:canEditRowAtIndexPath:)` according to Apple:

> Permits the data source to exclude individual rows from being treated as editable. Editable rows display the insertion or deletion control in their cells. If this method is not implemented, all rows are assumed to be editable. Rows that are not editable ignore the editingStyle property of a UITableViewCell object and do no indentation for the deletion or insertion control. Rows that are editable, but that do not want to have an insertion or remove control shown, can return [`UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone) from the [`tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone) delegate method.

I hope this help you.

Comment: @AbhishekMahesh I'm glad to help. Please if the answer solve your question accept it to help another one in the future.